# Kivy Camera speed? slow Performance

Tags: performance, camera, kivy, python-3.6

The Code works as expected except for one thing. The picture from the camera only updates about every 15 seconds. I'm wondering if there is a way to get it it run a little faster. I'm using an acer switch tablet with an intel atom processor which doesn't have a lot of horsepower so I was wondering if that could be part of my issue or maybe I should try using OpenCV to try to get the picture. for now it doesn't need to record video or save images just a live stream is all it needs to do.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
import time
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MainScreen(Screen):

    pass

class OptionsScreen(Screen):
    pass


class AlarmScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Project_1App(App):

    def build(self):
        screenManager = ScreenManager()
        screenManager.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main"))
        screenManager.add_widget(OptionsScreen(name="options"))
        screenManager.add_widget(AlarmScreen(name="alarm"))

        return screenManager

Project_1App.run()
```

The kivy bit is here

```
<MainScreen>:               

GridLayout:
    rows:5
    cols:1
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    Camera:
        index:0
        resolution: (300,300)
        play: True

    Button:
        text: "Options"
        size_hint_y: None

        width: 150
        height: 50

        on_release: root.manager.current = 'options'
```